# OpenCV 2.4.9 Full Screen

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, fullscreen

I am attempting to create an OpenCV application (in C++) that is full screen on the Raspberry Pi. I not been able to get my app be full screen yet. I have tried the following:

```
namedWindow("Image");
setWindowProperty("Image", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
// Create black empty images
Mat image = Mat::zeros(400, 400, CV_8UC3);

// Draw a circle 
circle(image, Point(200, 200), 32.0, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);
imshow("Image", image);

waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

However, this has only given me a window 400 by 400. I have referenced this post [Why does a full screen window resolution in OpenCV (@ Banana Pi, Raspbian) slow down the camera footage and let it lag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178361/why-does-a-full-screen-window-resolution-in-opencv-banana-pi-raspbian-slow) but it doesn't help. If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them. Thanks, Travis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

since the default WINDOW_AUTOSIZE flag [won't let you resize the window](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow)

also, just for clarity, use either:

```
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
setWindowProperty("Image", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 1); //( on or off)
```

or:

```
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL | WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );
```